# Deleting named objects in a Powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, object, powerpoint

I have some objects named"MYobject" in a PowerPoint presentation. I need a macro to delete those objects named "Myobject". How can I do that?

The code I  use to tag objects:

```
Sub TagObject()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        oSh.Tags.Add "Myobject", "YES"
    Next
    MsgBox "Done! Object has now been tagged.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "Please select an object before tagging.", vbExclamation
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to delete shapes named MYobject or do you want to delete shapes that have a "Myobject" tag whose value is "YES"?

Comment: I would like to delete all object with the "Myobject" tag, visible or not... Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete all shapes with a Myobject tag = "YES"

```
Sub DeleteMyObjects()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long

    ' note that this will not delete shapes
    ' within groups
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For x = oSl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If UCase(oSl.Shapes(x).Tags("Myobject")) = "YES" Then
                oSl.Shapes(x).Delete
            End If
        Next    ' Shape
    Next    ' Slide

End Sub
```

Comment: Steve, you are a STAR! Works perfectly! Many thanks sir. Regards, Philippe

Comment: how to delete tag from slide object

Comment: Simplest way to delete a tag is to set its value to ""  for example:  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Tags.Add "TagName", ""